# jq query parameter containing a variable

Tags: arrays, json, bash, shell, jq

I am using jq to parse an array. The query works fine when I use in the following format and use a fixed value inside double quotes e.g. 123456.

```
jq -r '.[] | select(.principalName=="123456") | .principalName' sp.txt
```

However I am getting the value from a variable in a bash script and I want to pass the variable (e.g. $spName) into jq parameter instead of a hard coded value 123456 something like:

```
jq -r '.[] | select(.principalName=="$spName") | .principalName' sp.txt
```

When I do so, I am getting error. Obviously my syntax is not correct. Can someone help me to fix the syntax?

Comment: Single quotes prohibit parameter expansion in bash. Therefore `jq` sees a literal `$spName`.

Answer (score -1):

Found what I was after. This one worked.

```
jq -r ".[] | select(.principalName==\"$spName\") | .principalName" sp.txt
```

Thank you both for your prompt response.